# Testflight app download error during TestFlight integration

Tags: iphone, sdk, testflight

This is testflight server error. Please try after sometime. during app installation through ipad mini

Answer (score 0):

Connect your iPad Mini to XCode, open `Organizer`, find your device in the side panel and open its `Console`. Clear the log and try, download the app and watch for any log messages. It will give you head start.